# Issue in T-SQL while checking null variable

Tags: sql-server, null, variable-length

I am writing a trigger in SQL Server like this

```
DECLARE @N_CATComp smallint, @EXON varchar(69), @DATEDEB varchar(15), @DATEFIN varchar(15)

SELECT 
    @N_CATComp = N_CATCompta, 
    @EXON =[Exon N°],
    @DATEDEB = CONVERT(varchar(15), [Date début] , 103), 
    @DATEDEB = CONVERT(varchar(15), [Date début] , 103) 
FROM INSERTED

IF  (@N_CATComp =4) AND  ( ISNULL(@EXON,'')='' OR ISNULL(@DATEDEB,'') ='' OR ISNULL(@DATEFIN,'') ='') 
BEGIN
     RAISERROR('false',11,1)
END
```

MY problem is that when @exon, @datedeb,@datefin are not null and catcomp=4 the raiserror appears which it shouldn't 
i tried to elpace isnull by for example len(@EXON)=0 in this case ven if the values are null then the raiserror don't appears

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. It incorrectly assumes there will only be a single row in INSERTED. triggers in sql server fire once per operation and the contents of triggers need to handle multiple row operations.

Comment: okay, if you have an example , would you offerd to me

Comment: The logic problem here is that if ANY of your variables are NULL or empty string the error will be raised.

Comment: I can't give you an example. You have to write your queries set based instead of scalar value based. For the condition you are checking here you would use an EXISTS and drop the scalar variables all together.

Comment: yes this is the logic but if they are not null the raisrror appears which is false

Comment: okay i will try what you suggest to me

Comment: But if EITHER of them are NULL or an empty string it will. Not sure why you are checking the same column more than once. And btw, these columns names are dreadful. You should not use spaces and special characters in column names.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the same thing with all those scalar variables removed.

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    from inserted
    where N_CATCompta = 4
        AND 
        (
            ISNULL([Exon N°], '') = '' 
            OR 
            ISNULL([Date début], '') = '' 
        ) 
)   
     RAISERROR('false',11,1)
```

Comment: thank you so much it works very well, i am very grateful